# jQuery Servlet call returns error

Tags: jquery, servlets

I make the simplest jQuery servlet call:

`jQuery:`

```
$.ajax( "LoginServlet" )
    .done(function() { alert("success"); })
    .fail(function() { alert("error"); });
```

`Servlet:`

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  System.out.println("Posting");
}
```

On the console, I see `Posting`, so the Servlet is called. However, I still get an 'error' alert.

Somewhere else, somebody mentioned a possible 'Cross Site Scripting' problem. Could that be the problem?

My servlet is at: `localhost:8080/Test/LoginServlet`

Comment: Check the javascript console and network tab in your browser for errors.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. It helped. Should have already checked the console myself of course. As it turns out, the button that caused the invocation in the first place, was a 'submit' button, causing the page to reload. Changed it to a 'button' button. Now everything works like a charm.

Comment: As an alternative, you can put an `e` parameter in your event handler function and call `e.preventDefault()`, which will prevent the refresh. Something like `$('button').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

Answer (score 0):

When you do the request your servlet does nothing just print in the console, you must manage the response of the cycle request/response.

So try with the following:

```
 // Obtain the out writer stream from the response 
 // object for send a response to the client (the web page)
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 // Print as response of request Posting
 out.println("Posting");
 // Close the out stream
 out.close();
```

Now your Jquery request will get a response.